# unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP Database driver error

Tags: oracle

I executed some heavy query on oracle. but one error is coming (unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP Database driver error)

I have checked the table space but TEMP table space is not found. below is the query that i have executed. And i have already increase the USER table space. but still facing same problem.

SELECT * FROM DBA_DATA_FILES;

```
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/users01.dbf    4   USERS   32212254720 3932160 AVAILABLE   4   YES 34359721984 4194302 160 32211206144 3932032 ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/undotbs01.dbf  3   UNDOTBS1    21474836480 2621440 AVAILABLE   3   YES 34359721984 4194302 640 21473787904 2621312 ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/sysaux01.dbf   2   SYSAUX  1377828864  168192  AVAILABLE   2   YES 34359721984 4194302 1280    1376780288  168064  ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/system01.dbf   1   SYSTEM  1073741824  131072  AVAILABLE   1   YES 34359721984 4194302 1280    1072693248  130944  SYSTEM
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/CSA_BILL_ITEM01.dbf    5   CSA_BILL_ITEM   32212254720 3932160 AVAILABLE   5   YES 32212254720 3932160 12800   32211206144 3932032 ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/CSA_BILL_ITEM_INDEX01.dbf  6   CSA_BILL_ITEM_INDEX 2147483648  262144  AVAILABLE   6   YES 2147483648  262144  3200    2146435072  262016  ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/CSA_BILL01.dbf 7   CSA_BILL    2147483648  262144  AVAILABLE   7   YES 2147483648  262144  12800   2146435072  262016  ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/CSA_BILL_INDEX01.dbf   8   CSA_BILL_INDEX  536870912   65536   AVAILABLE   8   YES 1073741824  131072  3200    535822336   65408   ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/META_DATA01.dbf    9   META_DATA   536870912   65536   AVAILABLE   9   YES 1073741824  131072  3200    535822336   65408   ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/META_INDEX01.dbf   10  META_INDEX  268435456   32768   AVAILABLE   10  YES 536870912   65536   640 267386880   32640   ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/POWERCENTER01.dbf  11  POWERCENTER 2147483648  262144  AVAILABLE   11  YES 2147483648  262144  4096    2146435072  262016  ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/CSA_QOTA01.dbf 12  CSA_QOTA_TBSPACE    536870912   65536   AVAILABLE   12  YES 536870912   65536   4096    535822336   65408   ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/CSA_QOTA02.dbf 13  CSA_QOTA_TBSPACE    1610612736  196608  AVAILABLE   13  NO  0   0   0   1609564160  196480  ONLINE
/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/CSA_QOTA03.dbf 14  CSA_QOTA_TBSPACE    1073741824  131072  AVAILABLE   14  NO  0   0   0   1072693248  130944  ONLINE
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: I infer that you're keeping table and index segments in different tablespaces. You may already know this, but alleged performance benefits of this are widely discredited.

Comment: I hit this error when running a query using the Oracle OCI8 driver, with a query that returns a large result set, but *not* through Oracle's SQL tool, SQL Developer, which uses the thin client. More detail on tuning the temp table here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350703/ora-01652-unable-to-extend-temp-segment-by-128-in-tablespace-system-how-to-ext?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

Temporary tablespaces are managed differently to normal data tablespaces. You can see the operating system files by querying `dba_temp_files` instead. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10595/tspaces007.htm#i1006555) for how to increase the size of a temporary tablespace file, or to add a new fle.

However, you might be better off investigating why your query is using so much temporary space and seeing if you can reduce it; there may be a fundamental mistake (like an accidental cross-join) that means it is using far more temp than it should, and probably making it run for much longer than it should. Have a look at the explain plan for clues to what's going wrong. Increasing `TEMP` may be necessary but shouldn't be done automatically as soon as you see this error.

Another option if you have a single query that needs far more temp than normal - and it's a one-off - might be to add a new temporary tablespace, [assign that to the user](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/network.112/e10574/users.htm#CHDCJDFJ) for the duration of the operation via `alter user`, revert when done, and then drop the new tablespace. Then the extra disk is only tied up for a short time. Might not be practical or sensible for your situation, but mentioned just in case.

---

I should say that true temporary temporary tablespaces - defined with [`create temporary tablespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_7003.htm#CJAFDEIF) - are managed like this, with entries in `dba_temp_files`. Prior to 8i they had normal datafilee, and it's possible to still have that configuration in a database that's been upgraded and not had the temporary tablespaces recreated in the new format. Clearly that isn't the case for you since yours do not appear in `dba_data_files`.