# Oracle Database Copy Failed Using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Few days ago while i tried perform database copy from remote server to local server i got some warnings and one of them was like this

> "Error occured executing DDL for TABLE:MASTER_DATA".

And then i clicked yes, but the result of database copy was unexpected, there were only few tables has been copied.

When i tried to see DDL from SQL section/tab on one of table, i got this kind of information

> -- Unable to render TABLE DDL for object COMPANY_DB_PROD.MASTER_DATA with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.

I also got this message and i believe this message showed up because there's something wrong with DDL on my database so tables won't be created.

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I've never encountered this problem before and i always perform database copy every day since two years ago.

For the record before this problem occurred, i have removed old .arch files manually not by RMAN and i never using any RMAN commands. I also have removed old .xml log files, because these two type of files have made my remote server storage full.

How to trace and fix this kind of problem? Is there any corruption on my Oracle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: i am currently using version 4.1.0.19

Comment: This is a generic error so can't say without analyzing the method that you have followed during the database copy.

Comment: using sql developer's database copy feature. and sorry i forget to mention both remote and local database using same version which is oracle 11g enterprise not express edition.


is there any correlation between removed .old arch files and this error? because before this problem happened, i did remove bunch .old arch files.  and correct me if i'm wrong, .arch files is used if we want to redo with RMAN, right? and i've never used any RMAN commands. i'm sorry i'm so confused.
thanks.

Comment: when i tried to see DDL scripts from SQL section/tab on one of table there's some changes. i can tell these changes because i compare with my old database table DDL scripts. and how exactly DDL scripts on table generated by oracle system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by datafile has reached its max size though. I have resolved the problem by following the answer of this discussion [ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM: How to extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350703/ora-01652-unable-to-extend-temp-segment-by-128-in-tablespace-system-how-to-ext)

Anyway, thank you everyone for the help.