# oracle alter statement to expand dbf file size

Tags: oracle

I get this error when I run a query against my Oracle db, which I believe indicates I need to expand my dbf file size:

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.
```

Based on that, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25350967/3368818) SO answer, which advises running the following:

```
select value from v$parameter where name = 'db_block_size';
```

That returns a value of `8192`. The same SO answer advises running an autoextend if the above returns a 'low max size'. So I decided to try that approach. I first get the location of my dbf file(s):

```
select name from v$datafile;
```

Which returns these 6 rows:

```
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/system.dbf
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/sysaux.dbf
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/undotbs1.dbf
/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/users.dbf
/opt/oracle/deploy/oradata/my_db_01.dbf
/opt/oracle/deploy/oradata/my_db_02.dbf
```

So I try to run an autoextend of `my_db_01.dbf`:

```
alter database datafile /opt/oracle/deploy/oradata/my_db_01.dbf autoextend on maxsize unlimited;
```

But that gives me:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02236: invalid file name
```

Why is the file name **invalid** when I'm pulling it directly from my v$datafile query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is that you've run out of space in `TEMP`.  If you're running a query, that is the space that Oracle uses for things like sorts and the like.  While it is certainly possible that you'd really want to extend the size of your `TEMP` tablespace, it is much more common that the issue is that the particular query you're running has a bug that is causing it to use excessive amounts of `TEMP` space.  If, for example, you've missed a join condition and you're creating a Cartesian product, throwing `TEMP` space at the problem is unlikely to fix it-- you'd need to fix the query.

If you're certain that the query is written correctly and you believe it is reasonable for it to need whatever `TEMP` space it is consuming, you'd need to look at `v$tempfile` or `dba_temp_files` to see the files associated with your temporary tablespace.

```
select file_name, 
       tablespace_name, 
       bytes/1024/1024 current_size_gb,
       maxbytes/1024/1024 max_size_gb,
       autoextensible
  from dba_temp_files;
```

If the `TEMP` files aren't already set to autoextend, you could set them to autoextend (note that the `file_name` has to be enclosed in single quotes)

```
alter database tempfile '<<path>>' autoextend on;
```

Comment: The key part of this answer for me was the file_name needs to be in single quotes. But the other info is also really helpful. Thanks!